# Angular composite forms submitted flag

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am looking to create a composite form control using angular material controls (Shown at angular connect https://youtu.be/CD_t3m2WMM8?t=1645). I am facing an issue with showing error messages on the individual controls once the entire outer form has been submitted. Material is using the parent form group directive to check if the form has been submitted or not and that drives whether error messages should be shown.

For my composite form

```
internalForm: FormGroup; // this form won't get submitted flag set to true when nested
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
     this.internalForm = fb.group({
       firstName: [],
       lastName:[]
     });
   }

<div [formGroup]="internalForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="First name" formControlName="firstName" minlength="5" required>
    <mat-error>Min length</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Last name" formControlName="lastName" minlength="5" required>
    <mat-error>Min length</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

Then when I want to use it

```
<h1>Composite Form</h1>
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ss-name-field formControlName="name"></ss-name-field>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The workaround is having my composite form not use the form group and just have individual form controls. This way the material controls can reach up and get access to the outer form group to check the flag. It will work fine for the above example but in my real world scenario, I want composite form controls of 5+ different controls so it would become a little messy.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-3vwszx